# How do i append child elements to the side of parent when height is exceeded

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```html
<ul style="height:200px;width:100%;">
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how i want it to look:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `column-count:2;`

```css
ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul style="height:200px;width:100%;">
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. use  column-count:2; and height property to ul

```css
ul {
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    max-height: 300px;
}

ul > li {
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hi</li>
</ul>
```